# Need help with little assembly language code

Tags: arduino, spi, attiny

Can anyone help me convert the below assembly language code to Arduino (Embedded C) code. I'm trying to program ATTiny24 as an SPI slave to establish communication between it and Arduino NANO (master).

```
init:
       ldi r16,(1<<USIWM0)|(1<<USICS1)
       out USICR,r16
...
SlaveSPITransfer:
                    out USIDR,r16
                    ldi r16,(1<<USIOIF)
                    out USISR,r16
SlaveSPITransfer_loop:
                    in r16, USISR
                    sbrs r16, USIOIF               //sbrs - skip if bit in register is set
                    rjmp SlaveSPITransfer_loop    //relative jump
                    in r16,USIDR
                    ret
```

I've only figured that the initialization part is written as:

```
USICR = USICR | (1<<USIWM0)|(1<<USICS1);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

init:
ldi r16,(1<<USIWM0)|(1<<USICS1)
out USICR,r16

becomes: USICR = (1<<USIWM0)|(1<<USICS1);
...

uint8_t slaveSPITransfer(uint8_t val)
{

```
USIDR = val;

USISR = (1<<USIOIF);

while (! (USISR & (1<<USIOIF))); //wait until complete

return USIDR;
```

}

Comment: Thanks Kartman bro for the answer... I'll implement it and let you know about the result.

Comment: I’d suggest you read and understand the datasheet so you can fully understand what the code is doing. I literally translated the code without any reference to the documentation. Also note that implementing a spi slave has a number of ‘challenges’. It is not quite as trivial as you would like.